# Blank space after each page when printing Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Why I'm getting a gap/spaces after each page when I print the result of Crystal Report?

I need to print an invoice on roll paper, but crystal report using fix height and size. I tried using the minimum amount of height and make it get multiple pages. But the problem now after I attempted to print it, it creates spaces between each page.

I have tried setting the margin into zero to minimize the gap, but it doesn't affect the gap.

Comment: source code? We cant go far without anything

Comment: i'm just trying to create an invoice through crystal report and preview it without any coding except sql for getting the data. i tried to print it using the preview report that crystal report give and print button.

Comment: If you select correct printer and paper size in report print options, then usually printer driver can handle roll papers itself (be sure not to have any unecessary white areas between report sections). What printer have you got?

Comment: i'm using epson lx-310. if i try to fit all the report to one page, i get all the correct position. but, im try to print on a roll paper that doesn't have fix height value. so i separating it into multiple page and try to print it at once. that's where this gap between each page occur.

Comment: Is your report really that high? Our printouts for these devices usually consist of short header (2-4cm), single (or double) line details and short footer (2-4 cm) - and they fit, even when there are tens of detail lines (CR may issue some page breaks, but printer driver seems to eliminate these). In print properties, you need to select 'continous roll' for paper size - is there such option? (Sorry, I have no receipt printer installed currently.)

Comment: if i separate them, the size of it only 8 cm for width and 3 cm for height each page.i don't know how to setting this printer to the "continuous roll" because i recently get this. the roll paper i mean not with the dot in each left and right, but the roll that like receipt from store. i'm just trying to make a receipt for POS for store and i'm stuck in this height problem when using crystal report.